# sudo cannot do cd

Tags: bash, sudo, cd-command

I found the strangest thing

```
sudo cd $pwd
sudo: cd: command not found
```

I am able to cd as a normal user.It seems that PATH is not set properly for su.

How do I fix that?

Comment: cd is not a program but an in-built command and sudo only applies to programs

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `cd` like below,

```
sudo cd $pwd
```

But you can do,

```
sudo su
cd $pwd
```

Comment: `sudo -i` is the cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't change directory as sudo.

sudo = Superuser Do [something]

what you can do is login as a superUser

> sudo su

do what you want (change directory, execute, edite file, etc). eg:

> cd [the_directory]

when you are done. logout superUser:

> exit

Comment: i think sudo means substitute user(rather than super user)

Comment: Instead of sudo su you should do `sudo -i`

Answer (score 0):

thats because "cd" is a shell bullitin

don't worry it doesn't work for anyone