# can't find conda but only when i use sudo

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have just install anaconda (python 2.7 version) in `/usr/local/bin`

I added `/usr/local/bin/anaconda2/bin/` to the path.

Now when I run `conda` from the command prompt it runs fine (but can't install anything without `sudo` because of the directory it's in).

However when I run the same command with `sudo` it can't find `conda`.

Does anyone know why this is?

Without `sudo`:

```
$ conda
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...

conda is a tool for managing and deploying applications, environments and packages.

Options:

positional arguments:
  command
```

With `sudo`:

```
$ sudo conda
sudo: conda: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to call conda with its absolute path :

```
 sudo /path/to/conda
```

You probably added conda location to your user $path but not to the sudo account

If this works, you can modify the $path for the root user the same way you did for your user

```
sudo export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

EDIT : export doesn't work with sudo, but you can change your path in /etc/sudoers (secure_path)

Comment: Ah thanks. It does work with the absolute path using sudo. However when i try to add to the path using sudo it tells me sudo: export: command not found. Surely export must be on sudo's path by default?

Comment: You're right, export doesn't work with sudo because it's a build in shell command

Comment: Try sudo -E conda

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo

Comment: @Grant `export` is a shell builtin - so `sudo export` fails for essentially the reason that [sudo cannot do cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419287/sudo-cannot-do-cd). It wouldn't help anyway because sudo uses its own `secure_path` defined in the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a similar situation; by trying to update conda it required permissions which I couldn't give because with sudo it didn't appear as well, so I tried to give permissions to my user like [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3448#issuecomment-282467541) post suggested but with miniconda3 and after running the update again it worked.